# SQL Server Trying to convert the data from rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I have table with data like as below

```
Crosswalk_id Code
ORG_201      1234
ORG_201      3456
ORG_201      3459
ORG_201      0983
ORG_201      2562
ORG_201      1239
```

need to convert this into

```
Crosswalk_id   C1    C2   C3    C4    C5    C6
ORG_201       1234  3456  3459  0983  2562  1239
```

Please help me to achieve this using pivot

Comment: And if you next time have seven rows, what then? Pivot can produce only fixed amount of columns, unless you start using dynamic sql - and even then you need to know beforehand, how many columns you need.

Comment: What determines the order of the data as well? Why is `'1234'` first and not `'0983'` or `'1239'`?

Comment: @Arvo I always say, when someone wants a rownumber pivot, there must be *some limit* on the maximum columns you want. Even Excel has a limit. So you can just pivot the maximum you would ever want.

Comment: @Charlieface Like they said, 640K ought to be enough for anybody ;)

Comment: @Arvo [16384](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) but I'd like to know who can view that many

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation with `row_number()`:

```
select crosswalk_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then code end) as c1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then code end) as c2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then code end) as c3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then code end) as c4,
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then code end) as c5,
       max(case when seqnum = 6 then code end) as c6
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by crosswalk_id order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by crosswalk_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **SQL Server PIVOT function**, it's made exactly for this purpose, i.e. transform rows to columns.

An [example of the PIVOT Function is available here](https://expert-only.net/sql-server/sql-server-pivot-table-rows-to-columns-query/) on this blog.

You must include an aggregation clause, the MAX() works pretty well for string values if you do not have duplicates lines.

For the full documentation, please check the [official Microsoft doc covering PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) functions.

NOTE: in your example, you only have one value "ORG_201", you might have more to use the function. And you need to name the columns, based on the values you expect in the [Code] column.

Answer (score 0):

Don't your IDs need to be different???

```
   -- DROP TABLE mytable

CREATE table mytable (
    id NVARCHAR(20),
    code NVARCHAR(5)
)
GO

INSERT INTO mytable ( id, code ) VALUES ( 'ORG_201', '1234')
INSERT INTO mytable ( id, code ) VALUES ( 'ORG_202', '3456')
INSERT INTO mytable ( id, code ) VALUES ( 'ORG_203', '3459')
INSERT INTO mytable ( id, code ) VALUES ( 'ORG_204', '0983')
INSERT INTO mytable ( id, code ) VALUES ( 'ORG_205', '2562')
INSERT INTO mytable ( id, code ) VALUES ( 'ORG_206', '1239')

SELECT      *
FROM     mytable

select * from
(

    SELECT id, code
    FROM mytable
) t
PIVOT (
    max(code)
    FOR id  IN ([ORG_201],[ORG_202],[ORG_203],[ORG_204],[ORG_205],[ORG_206])
) AS PivotTable;
```

[image]